# Inject factory into another Angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In order to set the base of my url in a factory call I need to call another factory's method to get the config. The below keeps throwing a `Provider 'reportService' must return a value from $get factory method.` error:

```
.factory('reportService', ['$resource', 'serverService',
  function($resource, serverService) {

    serverService.getConfiguration().$promise.then(function(config) {
      var base = config.reporting.url;
      return $resource(base, {}, {
        getReportResults: {method: 'POST', url: base + '/api/reports/:id/versions/:version'}
      });
    });
  }])
```

serverService:

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('serverService', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      var base = '/api/server/';
      return $resource(base, {}, {
        getConfiguration: {method: 'GET', url: base + 'configuration'}
      });
    }]);
```

Comment: Can we see the code for serverService?

Answer (score 1):

Your factory must return some function. Here in your `reportService`, you have defined the function but didn't return it.

Change it to the following,

```
.factory('reportService', ['$resource', 'serverService',
    function($resource, serverService) {
        return {
            function_one(): function() {
                return serverService.getConfiguration().$promise.then(function(config) {
                    var base = config.reporting.url;
                    return $resource(base, {}, {
                        getReportResults: {method: 'POST', url: base + '/api/reports/:id/versions/:version'}
                    });
                });      
            }, //add how many ever functions you want by separating with comma
            function_two: function() {
                // your second function
            }
        };
}]);
```

Now you can access your required function as follows in any controller,

```
reportService.function_one()
  .then(function (response) {
      // your logic
  });
```

Comment: When I add `return` in front of that function I get an `Expression or comma expected` warning in my IDE and an `Unknown provider: reportServiceProvider <- reportService <- reportQueueController` in the console.

Comment: @MattDionis I've made a syntax mistake. Can you check my edited answer?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a `factory` method, it should return an instance of object. And it will be invoke only when you `require/inject` it to another component.

In this case your `return` is inside the inner function so the function won't return any project.

It should be like this:

```
.factory('reportService', ['$resource', 'serverService',
  function($resource, serverService) {
    var base = config.reporting.url;
    function ReportService() {
      serverService.getConfiguration().$promise.then(function(config) {
        this.resource = $resource(base, {}, {
          getReportResults: {method: 'POST', url: base + '/api/reports/:id/versions/:version'}
        });
      }.bind(this));
    }
    return new ReportService()
  }])
```

More explaination:

1. a factory should return an object.

Ex:

```
.factory('message', function () {
  return "Hello World!"
}
```

so when it's injected to anther component, it will have a value of the returned object.

```
.controller('something', ['$scope', 'message', function ($scope, message) {}]);
```

then message will have value of 'Hello World!"

2. Return in inner function won't count.

Ex:

```
.factory('message', function () {
  http.get(...).then(function (data) {
    return "Hello World!"
  });
}
```

Comment: When running the above I get `reportService.getReportResults is not a function`. Note: I moved `var base = config.reporting.url;` inside `serverService.getConfiguration`.

Comment: You need to call like `reportService.resource.getReportResults`
can you explain what getConfiguration do? I think if it's a config you can put it into a javascript file and import it instead of calling async like that.